# Flutter How can I change the start and end day of the week?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a company app, but this company starts on Saturday and finishes on Thursday.Friday is a holiday.  6 day works.

I am using Jiffy package cause I need control the week number.
Start of week day monday and finish of week day Thursday.
I working API
and API connect Mysql. Mysql working same we changed the start of week day and finish day of the week.

But problem is  i need the send same week number. Every after the Friday
the week number is always missing.

How can I change in flutter the start of week day and the finish of week day ?

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/jama5262/jiffy/issues/64

Comment: I solved the problem in API